# Adjustable height of <footer> and dynamically reducing height of <content>

Tags: html, css

In `container` I have `navbar`, `content` (to display messages, fils up space beetween `navbar` and `footer`) and `footer` (with `textarea` and `button`). `Footer` is fixed to bottom of the page. Height of `footer` is rising (`navbar` direction) up to `textarea{rows={6}}` and at the same time `content` is getting smaller.

```
.container{
   position:relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.navbar{
   // not important
}
.content{
   max-height: 74vh;
   height: auto;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.footer{
   display: flex;
   position: fixed;
}
```

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='navbar'></div>
  <div class='content'></div>
  <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

With that configuration `footer` height is riseing but `content` is not getting smaller at the same time. Somebody can help?

Answer (score -1):

You can give the min-height: 89vh; to the container by which footer will be placed ate the bottom and no need to use position: fixed; in footer.`.container{min-height: 89vh;}`Please try this it may work.